# command line for counting specific word occurrences in a file (such as numbers of keys in a json)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, uniq

Kind of new to command line stuff, but looking for some pointers.

I use the following quick script to count how many times a key is in a json file:

```
grep -wo "\"keyname\"" "filename.json" | uniq -c
1200 keyname
```

It works well, but gets repetitive when I want to test counts of a bunch of keys...

```
grep -wo "\"key1\"" "filename.json" | uniq -c
1200 key1
grep -wo "\"key2\"" "filename.json" | uniq -c
1201 key2
grep -wo "\"key3\"" "filename.json" | uniq -c
1199 key3
```

So, I'd like to upgrade it to take an array of keynames, stored in a textfile,  rather than specify them individually in the keyname argument.  If that stays a one-liner, and stays [`cat`-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), even better.

I am not very good at one-liners, so here's what I tried instead:

(1) making a script called testkeys.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
grep -wo $line "filename.json" | uniq -c
done
```

(2) making a key file called keys.txt

```
key1
key2
key3
```

(3) Then

```
$ ./testkeys.sh keys.txt
```

However, this ran without completing.

Thoughts?

I was trying to find some way to make the lines of keys.txt into variables to go into a looped statement in the grep, but was unsuccessful.  Desired output would be...

```
$ magic? | grep -wo $vars "filename.json" | uniq -c
1200 key1
1202 key2
1199 key3
```

**UPDATE**

I know that grep can use the -f flag to take a pattern file as an argument, but this still seems to require a major change of the script in ways I don't understand.  So, for example...

Trying to convert...

```
grep -wo "\"keyname\"" "filename.json" | uniq -c
```

into...

```
grep -wo -F -f keys.txt "filename.json" | uniq -c
```

produces

```
1 key1
1 key2
1 key1
1 key2
1 key1
1 key2
```

... a bunch of times.  It also takes /much/ longer than the speed of each individual execution done n times.

I also tried this, which I thought would have been cool:

```
$ cat keys.txt | xargs -0 -I keyname grep -wo keyname "filename.json" | uniq -c
```

But this also ran for a long time and did not aggregate beyond count = 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uniq -c` counts the number of *consecutive* occurrences. So, you're almost there, you just need a `sort` :

```
grep -wo -F -f keys.txt "filename.json" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: You may also consider `grep -o 'key1\|key2\|key3\|key4' "filename.json" | sort | uniq -c` and compare the execution time.

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect.  Thanks.  I was really confused by my one-outputs.